# .NET Access Violation Exception with System.Drawing.dll / NumericUpDown

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'm suffering a really stupid problem. I've tried completely reinstalling .NET and it hasn't fixed the problem. I can't even find anyone else with the same problem by Googling.

Just on my computer, if I add a NumericUpDown control to a form in a .NET project and run the application, I get the following error message upon running the application:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.AccessViolationException'
>   occurred in System.Drawing.dll
>
> Additional information: Attempted to read or write protected
>   memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.

The application runs fine on other machines.

Any suggestions?

Comment: To be honest, if it's working fine on other machines then it could be anything, could be plugins you have running, could be malware, could be your memory.

Comment: You should look also at your project if you have any other Assemblies or Libraries that are potentially using Unmanaged Memory references and releasing them at the wrong time, I've seen this before from a commercial library. It was such a nasty problem for my project we had to remove the library completely because the error would appear randomly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem turned out to be graphics card related. We found a colleagues machine with the same issue, it just so happens both machines were recently fitted with the same cheap graphics card (Radeon HD5450). Both were running latest drivers.

No explanation as to why these cards/drivers caused this problem. but removing the cards and reverting to onboard graphics fixed the issue. The plan is to try a couple of cheap GEForce 210's instead.

I realise this wasn't a programming issue per se, but this might save someone else a few hours of fart arsing around!

Answer (score 2):

I also had a `System.AccessViolationException` with an error about reading protected memory when I would drag a **NumericUpDown** control onto a form in Visual Basic 2010 Express and then try to run the program. I am using graphics card ASUS EAH5450. Searching for a solution I found this post.

My 32bit XP system was using the driver supplied with the card, version 9.000. After uninstalling the driver, Catalyst Control Center, and GPU Tweak (all from the supplied DVD), I installed driver version 8.980 downloaded from their support link. Once installed the driver is dated 6/11/2012. I also installed Catalyst Control Center from that same download.

I added a **NumericUpDown** control to my form and ran the program and there was no error. Hardly conclusive proof of a fix, but a positive step and perhaps a viable solution with no hardware change.

My thanks to those who contributed to this thread.

Answer (score 0):

Just go in the VisualStudio  tools >> options >>Debugging >>JIT(Just-In-Time) and disable the check of managed ,native and script checkboxes.It has  solved the problem in my case .